# Issues with listeners and symbol errors

Tags: java, button, actionlistener

Halp!
Warning: lots of code ahead.

So I have an assignment and I feel like I'm getting very close to having it working. It compiles, and displays buttons.

Issue: When I press the buttons, no numbers come out.

Here's my directions:
Design and implement a program that displays a numeric key-
pad that might appear on a phone. Above the keypad buttons,
show a label that displays the numbers as they are picked. To the
right of the keypad buttons, include another button to clear the
display. Use a border layout to manage the overall presentation,
and a grid layout to manage the keypad buttons. Put a border
around the keypad buttons to group them visually, and a border
around the display.

Cliffs: Basically make a GUI that lets you punch in digits just like a phone.
Here's what my code looks like. I have a driver file and a file where most of the actual program is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Phonekeypadpanel extends JPanel
{

private JLabel tnum;
private JPanel pad, clr,title;
private JButton one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,clear,aster,pound;
private String num;



   public Phonekeypadpanel ()
   {
   //KEYPAD YO

   JPanel pad = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));
   setBackground (Color.red);   
   setLayout (new BorderLayout());

   one=new JButton ("1");
   two=new JButton ("2");
   three=new JButton ("3");
   four=new JButton ("4");
   five=new JButton ("5");
   six=new JButton ("6");
   seven=new JButton ("7");
   eight=new JButton ("8");
   nine=new JButton ("9");
   aster=new JButton ("*");
   zero=new JButton ("0");
   pound=new JButton ("#");

   pad.add(one);
   pad.add(two);
   pad.add(three);
   pad.add(four);
   pad.add(five);
   pad.add(six);
   pad.add(seven);
   pad.add(eight);
   pad.add(nine);
   pad.add(aster);
   pad.add(zero);
   pad.add(pound);

   one.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   two.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   three.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   four.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   five.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   six.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   seven.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   eight.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   nine.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   aster.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   zero.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
   pound.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

   //And here is the clear button.

   JPanel clr = new JPanel();
   clear= new JButton("CLR");
   clr.add(clear);
   clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

  //The buttons get added to a border layout here. 

   add(pad,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   add(clr,BorderLayout.EAST);

   //display code where pushed buttons will be seen.
   num = "";

   tnum = new JLabel();
   tnum.setText(num);
   add(tnum,BorderLayout.NORTH);

   }

  // Here we have the code for what to do when buttons are pressed.

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
  {

          if (event.getSource()==("1")) 

            {

             num = "1" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

            }else 

          if(event.getSource()==("2")) 

            {

             num = "2" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

            }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("3")) 
            {

              num = "3" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

            }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("4"))
           {

              num = "4" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

           }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("5"))
           {

              num = "5" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);
           }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("6")) 
          {

             num = "6" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("7")) 
          {

             num = "7" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);;

          }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("8")) 
          {

             num = "8" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("9")) 
          {

             num = "9" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("*")) 
          {

             num = "*" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }else 

          if (event.getSource()==("0")) 
          {

             num = "0" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }else 


         if (event.getSource()==("#")) 
         {

              num = "#" + num;
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

          }
          else
        if (event.getSource()==("CLR")) 
         {
                 num = "";
             tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

         }

   }

}
}
```

And you don't really need to look at this but here is my driver file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Phonekeypad
{


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Phone Keypad");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.getContentPane().add(new Phonekeypadpanel());
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Indentation ftl. Do you have a trace that shows where these symbol errors occur?

Comment: Just edited my post to include the location of the errors.

Comment: `private string num` needs a capital on `string`. There is no `string` class.

Comment: See my answer at the bottom

Comment: It's running now. But now when I press the buttons, it doesn't show up in the display.

Also, tfw my formatting is never good enough for this site.

Comment: You need to use `display.setText("someText")` inside the if statement in the buttonlistener. See my edited answer

Comment: Also, why do you declare your labels twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `tnum` and `num` are being declared both in the class `Phonekeypadpanel` and in the constructor.  When you try to assign values to them, you end up only changing a local copy residing in the constructor and not the class variables.  Change the line `String num = "";` into `num = "";` and change `JLabel tnum = new JLabel();` into `tnum = new JLabel();`.

Finally, replace each `"one"`, `"two"`, etc. with `"1"`, `"2"`, etc. because when you put `System.out.println(event.getActionCommand());` at the top of `actionPerformed` you'll see the output is the label of the button.

Comment: Isn't the name of the button "one" "two", etc, and "1" and "2" the output? You lost me in the first paragraph a bit.

Comment: The _variable_ _names_ are `one`, `two`, etc. but their labels are `1`, `2`, etc.  `event.getActionCommand` in this case will return the labels on the JButtons (the text that the user sees).

Comment: Okay, I did just that. Still not outputting numbers. I'll edit the code above so you know what it looks like.

Comment: Oh wow...wow. WOWWW. I have been working on this code for the last two days. Finally. Thank god, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
private String num;
```

not

```
private string num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `e.getActionCommand()`, but there is no `e`, it should be `event`.

```
else if (event.getActionComand().equals("three")){
    ...
}
```

`event` is tour `ActionEvent` variable, not `e`.  That's why the `can't find symbol`. Your just missing on the "three"

And

```
Jlabel display = new JLabel ("Phone Number ");
```

No such class `Jlabel`. Should be `JLabel`

**Edit:** To display text

```
if (event.getActionCommand().eqauls("three")){
    num += "3";
    display.setText(num);
}
```

Comment: Explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish. I'm probably missing something here

Comment: try using `if(event.getSource() == one){}`.  Honestly I've never used `getActionCommand()` so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: I reread the directions, it wants a label to display the buttons pressed, not a text field. So I changed the code a bit.

Basically, you press buttons on a phonepad looking thing and above the buttons, the numbers you press come out on a label. And then you can press CLR to get rid of them.

Comment: Given everything else is correct, `yourLabel.setText("yourText");` should work.

Comment: I have the set text as:
   tnum.setText("Telephone number: " + num);

Comment: The if statements look like this: if (event.getSource()==("four"))

Comment: You can't use that. When you use `getSource()` you need to use the variable name `one`, which is your button variable name

Comment: Should be `if (event.getSource() == one){}`. If that doesn't get you an output, there's something else wrong with your code. You may want to update your post to show what you have so far